# AngularJS & jQuery Mobile range slider won't update model

Tags: jquery, mobile, angularjs, slider, range

This is my jQueryMobile Page with AngularJS:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Chart</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="plotChart" class="myChart"></div>
        <form>
            <input type="range" value="0" min="-10" max="10" ng-init="0" ng-model="value1" ng-change="update()"/>
            <input type="range" value="0" min="-10" max="10" ng-init="0" ng-model="value2" ng-change="update()"/>
            <input type="range" value="0" min="-10" max="10" ng-init="0" ng-model="value3" ng-change="update()"/>
        </form>
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">Value1: {{value1}}</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">Value2: {{value2}}</div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:60px">Value3: {{value3}}</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My update function looks like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.update = function(){
        console.log("C=" + $scope.value3 + "B="+$scope.value2 + "A="+$scope.value1);
    }
}
```

The {{value1-3}} on the page is updated correctly when moving the sliders
The update function keeps logging zero when moving the sliders.

Why? Are the here different scopes involved?

(Also the sliders have -10 as initial value - not -10 as defined)
jquery-1.9

- jquery-1.9.1.min.js
- jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js
- jquery-mobile-angular-adapter-1.3.1.js

Comment: May be it will be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20802111/1206613

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-init=0` won't set any scope properties.  [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) expects an Angular expression, which is evaluated against the scope.  You could write `ng-init='value1 = 0'` but it is better to initialize model values in your controller:

```
$scope.value1 = 0;
```

`value = 0` should not be used with Angular form elements (except for `type=radio`).

Here is a [minimal fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/nBd86/) that only includes Angular, and only shows the changes I talked about above.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I can't figure out is if your code had a minimal change compared to the full version of my code or if this was a caching problem yesterday evening...

Comment: Mark, any idea why the range model binding isn't working on IE10? (yeah, yeah, I know, going for maximum compatibility).  IE10 doesn't work on either my code or your jsFiddle

Comment: Further research, and the comments in this question have more information http://stackoverflow.com/q/16310707/524511
In short, webkit is 'helping' angular by raising an extra event for ranges - an event that is normally for text boxes.