# Angular doesn’t support input type=”range” in IE10

Tags: svg, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

When the value of an HTML5 `<input type=”range”>` element is changed in Chrome or Safari, angular detects the change. But in IE10 (on Windows 8, Windows Server 2012 and Windows Phone 8) the change seems to be ignored in both Angular v1.0.6  and v1.1.4. Firefox 20.0.1 doesn’t support this input type.

Try these two (third-party authored) fiddles to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/fRgtF/,
http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/nBd86/.

I can imagine a couple of quick fixes but as I’ll be using this is in a B2B context the key factors are stability, reliability and ease of long-term maintenance. With that in mind, can anyone help with these two questions:

(1) If I want to use `<input type=”range”>` in IE10 what’s the correct way to get Angular to detect changes in the input value? I don’t mind using lower-level Angular functions to get the right result.

(2) If I decide to use a sliding range input widget instead of the HTML5 element, does one already exist and/or are there any starting points (ideally svg-oriented) that would significantly help me build my own?

Comment: There is an Angular ticket saying [range isn't supported](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1189) but it does seem to work, at least on Chrome.The root problem is that Angular seems to be listening for the "input" event, which IE10 doesn't fire on the range. However, IE10 does fire a "change" event, I just don't know how to tell Angular to listen to it. There is some [dubious code using browser sniffing](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a348e90aa141921b914f87ec930cd6ebf481a446/src/ng/sniffer.js#L53) that seems to need updating.

Comment: @Dave, thanks. As you said, angular doesn't support `<input type="range"` yet. Per the 1.1.4 source code, when inputDirective doesn't recognize the type, it defaults to text input, which listens for the `oninput` event. IE never fires that event when a range input is changed, Chrome fires it when you mouse the thumb, but not when you move it with the keyboard, and Firefox Nightly fires it for both keyboard and mouse changes. I think I'd be better off building my own slider widget, so I'm still interested in knowing the best practice for wiring SVG and angular together....