# Input range and ng-change not working in IE.

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

As you can see in my example ng-change is'nt triggered in IE when using input type range;
http://jsfiddle.net/0my6kzmh/2/

```
    <div ng-app>
        <div ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
        {{val}}
        <input type="textbox" ng-model="value" /><br>
        <input type="range" ng-change="updateVal()" min-value="0" ng-model="value" max-value="100"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value=45;
    $scope.val='test IE';

    $scope.updateVal = function(){
        console.log("not triggered in ie");
    };    
}
```

And when changing range value in slider it does'nt update my model value used by textbox.

Should I avoid using ng-change for type range?

Suggestion of good solution for this to work in IE? (I am testing IE11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not supported in ie  ( a bug  ). see this link, it  may help you
       [Angular doesn’t support input type=”range” in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310707/angular-doesn-t-support-input-type-range-in-ie10)

Comment: Thank you Furkan! I think this solution works for now even if its not the prettiest: http://jsfiddle.net/hRDVS/